# Socketio undefined results

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

a few days ago I tried to train with react by creating a real-time chat application, but I'm a bit lost in the io socket, I can't send a message or notification on a specific user, I get an "undefined" error, here is my socket io code:
I tried to retrieve the user with the id as receiverId but socket io returns me undefined

about this function:
`socket.on("friendRequest", ({ senderId, receiverId }) => { const receiver = getUser(receiverId); console.log(receiver) });`

How can I fix this error,

thank you very much
And sorry for my English,

````
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = require('./router');
//const { Socket } = require('dgram');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);


app.use(router);
app.use(cors());

let users = [];
const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
  !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) &&
    users.push({ userId, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

const getUser = (userId) => {
  return users.find((user) => user.userId === userId);
};
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected.");

  socket.on("addUser", (userId) => {
    addUser(userId, socket.id);
    io.emit("getUsers", users);
  });

  socket.on("sendNotification", ({ senderId, receiverId, type }) => {
    const receiver = getUser(receiverId);
    io.to(receiver.socketId).emit("getNotification", {
      senderId,
      type,
    });
  });

  socket.on("friendRequest", ({ senderId, receiverId }) => {
    const receiver = getUser(receiverId);
    console.log(receiver)
  });

  socket.on("sendText", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
    const receiver = getUser(receiverId);
    io.to(receiver.socketId).emit("getText", {
      senderId,
      text,
    });
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User Disconnected", socket.id);
    removeUser(socket.id);
    io.emit("getUsers", users);
  });
});

app.use(router);

server.listen(PORT,() => console.log('Server has started on port ${PORT}'));```
````

Comment: In the client are you writing the "receiverId" correctly? when you emit the event.

Comment: @AngelHdz  Yes like this: <br>`socket.emit("friendRequest",{
   senderId: this.props.user.id,
   receiverId: id,
  })`

Comment: try to log the ```receiverId``` in the server to see where the problem is

Comment: @Angel thank you for your answer, I already tried, the problem comes from here `const receiver = getUser(receiverId);` it can't find the getUser function, Thanks